# how to call react component from js function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

In my react js application has below js function that gets called from mobile device. Now i want to call react component from this js fuction. please guide.

```
var externalcall = {
    callme:function(value)  {
             //here i want to call a react component

        } catch (ex) {
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: What do you mean saying "call react component"? Are you trying to render a react component?

Comment: yes, somehow want to communicate react component from external js file(function)

Answer (score 0):

You can import the require Component using import(ES6) or require. Further, return the component inside your function.

```
import Component from './src';

        var externalcall = {
            callme:function(value)  {
                     return <Component />
                } catch (ex) {
                }
            }
        };
```